# How to refactor ActiveRecord query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, refactoring

I have a code in controller:

```
def latest
  @latest_articles = user_signed_in? ? Article.limit(10).order(id: :desc).pluck(:id, :title) : Article.where("status = ?", Article.statuses[:public_article]).limit(10).order(id: :desc).pluck(:id, :title)
  render json: @latest_articles
end
```

How to refactor it to looks elegant?
I tried using lambda:

```
extract = lambda {|a| a.order(id: :desc).pluck(:id, :title)}
Article.limit(10) {|a| a.extract}
```

but it returns only `Article.limit(10)`

UPD: I need to get last 10 of all articles if user is signed in, and last 10 of only public ones if not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would create an initial scope, and modify it based on some conditions:

```
def latest
  scope = Article.order(id: :desc)
  scope = scope.where(status: Article.statuses[:public_article]) if user_signed_in?

  render json: scope.limit(10).pluck(:id, :title)
end
```

Comment: Also `where('status =  ?', <expr>)` can be written as `where(status: <expr>)`.

Comment: thanx, but when user is not signed in and there are, for example 2 private articles among 10 last articles, I will get only 8 articles. I need to get last 10 of all articles if user is signed in and last 10 public ones if not

Answer (score 2):

You could refactor as

```
@lates_articles = Article.all
@lates_articles = @latest_articles.where("status = ?", Article.statuses[:public_article]) unless user_signed_in?
render json: @latest_articles.limit(10).order(id: :desc).pluck(:id, :title)
```

But it would be better to create model method

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  scope :latest, -> {last(10).order(id: :desc)}

  def self.public user_signed
    if user_signed
      all
    else
      where("status = ?", statuses[:public_article])
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

Then you would use it like

```
def latest
  render json: Article.public(user_signed_in?).latest.pluck(:id, :title)
end
```

Comment: Looks nice in the controller, but mixes two independent scopes. Doesn't scale nice if you need something similar like latest unread articles...

Comment: And as Uncle Bob would probably say: "Boolean arguments loudly declare that the function does more than one thing."

Answer (score 0):

final version:

```
def latest
  scope = Article.order(id: :desc)
  scope = scope.shared unless user_signed_in?
  render json: scope.limit(10), except: [:body, :created_at, :updated_at]
end
```